# How to Refresh ListView.Builder when data changes in background?

Tags: flutter

I have a `ListView` which gets data from API, the API call is first made from `initState()` and assigning to `List<DataFromApi> dataFromApi = [];`. After sometime am doing a background call again to the same API, Am getting the data and assigning to the same list `dataFromApi` in

```
setState(() {
  dataFromApi = [];
  for (DataFromApi td in resData.data) {
    dataFromApi.add(td);
  }
});
```

When logging it, the data changes, but UI not changing. How can I update the ListView?

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
    List<DataFromApi> dataFromApi = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    loadData();
    super.initState();
    fetchFirstData();
    initTimedDataCall();
  }

  initTimedDataCall() {
    Timer.periodic(Duration(minutes: 5), (timer) {
      setState(() {
        timedCall();
      });
    });
  }
  
  fetchFirstData() async {
    final response = await http.get(
      Utils.getDataUrl,
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final resData = DataListFromJson(response.body);
      if (resData.status == 1) {
        print(response.body);
        setState(() {
          dataFromApi = [];
          for (DataFromApi td in resData.data) {
            dataFromApi.add(td);
          }
        });
      }
      ///
      ///
      /// DOING SOME MORE THINGS IN FIRST CALL
      ///
      ///
    }
  }

  timedCall() async {
    final response = await http.get(
      Utils.getDataUrl,
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final resData = DataListFromJson(response.body);
      if (resData.status == 1) {
        print(response.body);
        setState(() {
          dataFromApi = [];
          for (DataFromApi td in resData.data) {
            dataFromApi.add(td);
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: dataFromApi.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Text('${dataFromApi[index].title}');
            }
            ),
    );
  }


}
```

Comment: Generally it is recommended that the `setState` method only be used to wrap the actual changes to the state, not any computation that might be associated with the change. 
Can you remove the `timedCall()` method from `setState` in the `initTimedDataCall`

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `setState` after computation is done

```
 timedCall() async {
    final response = await http.get(
      Utils.getDataUrl,
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final resData = DataListFromJson(response.body);
      if (resData.status == 1) {
        print(response.body);
          dataFromApi = [];
          for (DataFromApi td in resData.data) {
            dataFromApi.add(td);
          }
        setState(() {
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

use similar for other methods. This is working at my end